# Testing .NET 6 app configured with identity using postman

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, postman

I have a .NET 6 application that is configured to use identity for authorization and would like to test other controllers in the application. I've tried using postman but the request keeps returning a 404 error.

[image]

I tried using postman interceptor to capture the credentials from the request but could not figure out how to use them.

[image]

I also tried setting up the app to use cookies but nothing seems to be happening.

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
});
```

Comment: " I've tried using postman but the request keeps returning a 404 error" Do you try url request ike : https://localhost:your port/Controller/Action  ?

Comment: yes. The structure of the request is : https://localhost:44376/User/RetrieveUsers.

Comment: What project type you're using? 
Could you provide a minimal reproducible example including both the C# code ? You can set a breakpoint at  RetrieveUsers action to see if it excute it .

Comment: The project type is asp.net web app. Controller :  `[Route("RetrieveUsers"), HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            // git test
            var users = repository.GetUsers();
            if (users == null || users.Count == 0)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(users);
        }`  The break point is not hit as the request returns 404 when sent from postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you add below code to your Program.cs?

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
...
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You can have a look at [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  to know more.

Try to add the above route for mvc.

result:
[image]

Comment: i didn't. Let me look that up

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @TheColonel ,You are welcome:) If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?  Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thank you very much.

Comment: Done. Hope you have a lovely day.